# Will Navigation Controller Push stops animation on previous view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I make an UIImageView animate a series of pictures in a view under control of an UINavigationController.

When push to another view, will this view stops animating automatically?

Comment: It depends on how you perform animation.

Comment: @Max [UIImageview startAnimation];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation still look running during the a new view is push to the navigation controller. However, when you navigate back to the view, the animation image is no longer visible or stop running. If you want to stop the animation during the push, you can call the [animatedImageView stopAnimating] before the push, and start the animation again by calling [animatedImageView startAnimating] in the view controller method viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't stop animation. You have to do that manually (e.g. in viewDidDisapper).